# Adobe Acrobat Reader 8 for Solaris 8?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, solaris

Has anyone got anything more recent than Acrobat 4 working on Solaris 8.
I realize the OS is obsolete but we have un-ported software.

Comment: I guess there are not many people working with solaris anyways...this question seems to fit better for a solaris forum.

Comment: @jscott
Thank you so much for the information. I really fed up with the installation of adobe reader in solaris 8. Adobe reader 5 is working fine in solaris 8 URL: Adobe reader 5 for Solaris 8 ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobatreader/unix/5.x/solaris-509.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

There are 8.1.7 binaries for Sparc on the [Adobe FTP site](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/8.x/8.1.7/enu/).  But the README indicates Solaris 9.

[Version 5.09's](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobatreader/unix/5.x/), which is a *wee* bit newer than version 4, README indicates it supports Solaris 8 :)